# TableView reloadData does nothing with custom dataSource class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created a custom UITableViewDataSource class. When it's initialized, I set the tableView's delegate and dataSource to `self`, but when reloadData() is called, none of the dataSource method is invoked and the tableView that was passed in has no changes. (I omitted the delegate code below for clarity.)

```
class TopicsDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var topics: [String : Topic] = [:]
    var cellConfigBlock: ((UserTopicCell, Topic) -> ())? = nil
    var tableView: UITableView!
    var user: User!

    init(tableView: UITableView, user: User) {
        super.init()
        self.tableView = tableView
        self.user = user
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        self.getData() // Call reloadData
    }

    func getData() {
        let rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            let updateGroup = DispatchGroup()
            for tid in self.user.topicIDs!.keys {
                updateGroup.enter()
                rootRef.child("topics/" + tid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snp) in
                    let newTopic = Topic(json: (snp.value as! [String : Any]), completion: {
                        updateGroup.leave()
                    })

                    self.topics.updateValue(newTopic!, forKey: snp.key)

                })
            }

            updateGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
                // Notice: the dataSource reference of tableView is weak
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }

    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let topic = Array(topics.values)[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "topicCell") as! UserTopicCell
        if let config = cellConfigBlock {
            config(cell, topic)
        }
        cell.topic = topic
        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return topics.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // Delegate Methods ...
}
```

Comment: have you tried to replace this line `tableView.dataSource = self` with `self.tableView.dataSource = self`

Comment: @RahulPatel Yes. Still not working.

Comment: check if your tableview is coming nil on the reload line

Comment: Please show how you are using `TopicsDataSource` in Viewcontroller

Comment: @MikeAlter In view controller viewDidLoad: let _ = TopicsDataSource(tableView: self.topicTableView, user: self.user)

Comment: @RahulPatel It's not nil.

Comment: calling this numberOfRowsInSection method at least one time?

Comment: from where `topics` dict comes ?

Comment: @MikeAlter It appears topics.count is 0. Am I using DispatchGroup improperly?

Comment: @MikeAlter. When using TopicsDataSource class in View Controller, You need create object of your datasource class and set it equal to datasource of table view. After this when you reload your table delegates will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in that case you have to custom the reload data too along with your custom data source and custom delegates for your table view.

Comment: I don't think we can custom reloadData without subclassing UITableView. reloadData would automatically call tableView's dataSource and delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not show the code to set the tableview delegate. What class acts as the tableview delegate? Is it your custom class? If so, you should have something like the following in your set up code:

```
tableView.delegate = <Reference to custom class>
```

Comment: This class is also the delegate. I omitted all the code for delegate in the post.

Comment: The easiest way to get an answer in that case would be to upload your project somewhere and provide a link. Then anybody interested can run it to see what is going on instead of trying to figure out the issue based on part of the code :)